# Div перетаскиваемые Drag в принимающий div Drop

Tags: css3, jquery, javascript, ui, html5

Есть div в котором лежат несколько div одного размера и они могут быть перетаскиваемы. Когда div сбрасывают в приемник, то он становиться заранее назначенной картинкой. Таких div много и у каждого div своя картинка.

Answer (score 2):

Ну так в чем проблема? Возьмите и сделайте так. Нужному `div` выставляете `draggable="true"`, а на событие `drop` проверяйте куда бросили: http://jsfiddle.net/RubaXa/heAHM/

Comment: извините, я чаник. т.ч. вас не понял

Comment: Чем с мог, тем помог, вот ещё небольшой пример c картинками: http://jsfiddle.net/RubaXa/heAHM/1/

Comment: спасибо большое, очень близко. а как сделать перетаскиваему первому диву картинку html, второму css и третьему js и не зависимо куда я их кладу они принимают свою картинку?